# Why is C application not printing message first then taking in user input

Tags: c, eclipse, fgets

I'm trying to write a c application that prints prompts and takes user input.  I wrote a simple program with fgets(), but it did work right.  I'm using eclipse c/c++ toolkit.  When I save>build>run the console stays blank.  If I put in some input, the program then runs.  First it prints the printf then the input I entered.  I tried running a sample program I found on the web instead, but it ran with the same issues.  Anyone got any ideas about why?
What I'm trying to get is:
"Who are you?"
input = "rice"
"Glad to meet you rice"

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char name[10];
    printf("Who are you? ");
    fgets(name,10,stdin);
    printf("Glad to meet you, %s",name);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to flush stdout, which is normally line-buffered by default.  Just add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, That worked! Do you know why the missing "fflush(stdout) caused this error?

Comment: Yes, as I said, stdout is line-buffered by default.  That means that output is buffered until a newline character is sent.  Normally output ends in a newline, but when prompting for input, it often doesn't, which is why you need to explicitly flush it.

Comment: If I have multiple prompts do I need fflush(stdout) after each?

Comment: If they don't end in a newline, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not flushed the output buffer. If the output does not end in a newline, it may remain buffered as in this case:

```
printf( "Who are you? " ) ;
fflush( stdout ) ;
```

should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, missing the fflush(stdout) was the problem.  (I'm marking this answer as the solution, but it should be noted that Tom Karzes gave the same answer in a comment before this was posted)

Comment: @RiceMan : Choosing to post an answer in a comment is Tom's problem.  If he wants credit, he should post an answer.  I had not in fact read the comment.  However it is a common error and is probably a duplicate of a question already on SO and is likely to be closed.

Comment: This is insufficient to explain the behavior reported in the question, because soliciting input should flush the output buffer, so `fflush(stdout);` would have no additional effect. Per C 2018 7.21.3 7, if standard output refers to an interactive device (and therefore cannot be determined not to refer to an interactive device), it is unbuffered or line buffered. Per 7.21.3 3, if it is unbuffered, characters are sent immediately, and, if it is line buffered, characters are sent when input is requested on a stream that requires characters from the host environment (see paragraph 3 for details).

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code unchanged into a blank file, compiled it with gcc on Ubuntu and it runs exactly as you want it to:

```
j@j:~/Desktop/C$ make

gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g 1.c -o 1 -lm

j@j:~/Desktop/C$ ./1
```

---

```
Who are you? rice

Glad to meet you, rice
```

This has to be an issue with Eclipse IDE setup environment, the OS, etc.
The C code itself is fine.

Comment: I agree, I ran the code on a virtual machine (Ubuntu) before I posted and it compiled without error.  However I've used eclipse and netbeans on my windows OS without issues in the past so it didn't make sense why it would fail now.  Tom Karzes solution fixed the problem, but I would like to know why missing the fflush(stdout) caused this issue in the first place.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RiceMan ; Different platforms different behaviour.  Linux has a concept of a console being a "terminal" where line buffering serves a useful purpose in a multi-user system with remote terminals. On a modern system the terminal us normally "virtual" and just an emulation.  Windows was never a multi-user system and has always had its console directly coupled to the system rather than conceptually a remote terminal, so does not normally line buffer output.  If you want portability, you need to flush the output.

Comment: Eclipse and Netbeans are IDEs not compilers so have no effect on the code generation - they are not the reason it may have worked in WIndows.  The issue is runtime environment, not the compiler and certainly not the IDE.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for the clarifying comments.  That is good info.